# Spring Security form post authentication

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a page to access with form post request *(webview page for mobile apps)*. My application can't have a login form but I need to secure it. Mobile applications will call this webview page with authentication parameters such as (email/password). I need to call third-party api with given authentication parameters and decide it was authenticated or not. Which approach should I use for my scenarios ?

Comment: Are you responsible for these mobile apps, or will these be developed by other people? If it's the latter (or arguably the former too), it sounds like you're expecting the third party mobile apps to store (or at least, handle) credentials for your system. That doesn't strike me as the most secure approach - what happens when the third party app has a breach, and loses you users' credentials? Perhaps better to look into OAuth or similar?

Comment: See OWASP: https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Authentication_Cheat_Sheet.html#use-of-authentication-protocols-that-require-no-password (that link doesn't seem to work correctly for me, it should be taking to you to the section titled "Use of authentication protocols that require no password")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it possible to pass authentication parameters in the `Authorization` header, you can enable http basic authentication in your application:

```
    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .httpBasic();
    }
```

*Otherwise, you can implement your own security filter to create a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken` (or any other class implementing `Authentication`) instance from your specific authentication parameters and pass to `AuthenticationManager`; but in the case of another class, you need to make the authentication provider below support it by overriding the `public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication)` method.*

Then implement a custom `AuthenticationProvider` that will delegate authentication to the third-party API, e.g.:

```
public class RestAuthenticationProvider extends AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider {

    private static final String AUTH_URL = "http://third-party-service/authentication/basic";
    private RestTemplate restTemplate;

    public RestAuthenticationProvider() {
        this.restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Override
    protected void additionalAuthenticationChecks(UserDetails userDetails, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        if (authentication.getCredentials() == null) {
            this.logger.debug("Authentication failed: no credentials provided");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
        if (!authentication.getCredentials().toString().equals(userDetails.getPassword())) {
            this.logger.debug("Authentication failed: invalid credentials");
            throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected UserDetails retrieveUser(String username, UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication) {
        String password = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        try {
            ResponseEntity<String> authenticationResponse = authenticate(username, password);
            if (authenticationResponse.getStatusCode().value() == 401) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException(this.messages.getMessage("AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.badCredentials", "Bad credentials"));
            }
            return createUser(authenticationResponse.getBody());
        } catch (BadCredentialsException ex) {
            throw ex;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }

    private ResponseEntity<String> authenticate(String username, String password) {
        HttpEntity entity = new HttpEntity(createHeaders(username, password));
        return restTemplate.exchange(AUTH_URL, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
    }

    private HttpHeaders createHeaders(String username, String password) {
        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.set("Content-Type", "application/json");
        String authorization = username + ":" + password;
        String basic = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authorization.getBytes());
        headers.set("Authorization", "Basic " + basic);
        return headers;
    }

    private UserDetails createUser(String json) {
        return null; // TODO: Implement
    }
}
```

And finally, make Spring Security to use your provider:

```
    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) {
        auth.authenticationProvider(new RestAuthenticationProvider())
                .eraseCredentials(false);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for detail explanations and useful code examples.

Comment: @Cataclysm could you accept my answer if it works for you?

Comment: If my view method is `@PostMapping("/secure/page1")` , how your provided `RestAuthenticationProvider` will intercept and authenticate it ? And how do the `RestAuthenticationProvider` will pick up `username,password` parameters ?

Comment: `http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().authenticated()`  requires all requests to be authenticated. If you use HTTP basic authentication `username` and `password` will be obtained from the `Authorization` header by `BasicAuthenticationFilter` and passed to `RestAuthenticationProvider` through `AuthenticationManager`, otherwise you need to implement a custom filter.

Comment: Thank you again. Now I'm trying to figure it out with your suggestions, your code examples and a link https://leaks.wanari.com/2017/11/28/how-to-make-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-with-spring-security. And please edit your answer with above comment bcos it is very useful and related with my question. But I do not use HttpBasic Authentication. I am using with custom filter as [This website link](https://leaks.wanari.com/2017/11/28/how-to-make-custom-usernamepasswordauthenticationfilter-with-spring-security)

Comment: now I'm stucking at redirecting problem after successfully authenticated. I don't want to redirect anywhere for form-post processing after authenticated. I just need to continue process.

Comment: The answer already mentions the use of a custom filter, and how Spring Security works has nothing to do with the question. There are no redirects in my code, and I have no idea what you are doing. If you need more help, complete your question with code examples.

Comment: Yes .. you helped me alot and your answer leads me the way to solve my problem. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to call third-party api with given authentication parameters
>   and decide it was authenticated or not

Assuming you need to use username / password to send to 3rd party, when you first login into the app, you can create a long lived token in back-end and sent it to the app to store in secure store. Later when you want to load the protected webview, send this token along with the request (in header or body via javascript) and in the server side pick the user / password corresponding to the token and authenticate with 3rd party.
This way you will never need to store password on client side and you can manually make the token at backend inactive too. If you like to go standard way, then you may take a look at [Password Grant](https://oauth.net/2/grant-types/password/) of OAuth 2 / OpenID Connect / . With the correct infrastructure in place you can get access tokens during login process and use that for your protected page. Spring Security has support for this flow - you can take a look [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security-oauth2-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#oauth2-boot-authorization-server-password-grant).